# Creating NumPy array with Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use scikit with some data that are in one spreadsheet (.xlsx). To achieve this I'm using Pandas to read the spreadsheet and then I was going to use numpy to use scikit.

The problem here is that when I covert my DF structure to numpy, I lose almost all the data! I think it is because it doesn't have columns names. There are just raw data. EX:

28.7967 16.0021 2.6449  0.3918  0.1982

31.6036 11.7235 2.5185  0.5303  0.3773

162.052 136.031 4.0612  0.0374  0.0187

My code so far:

```
def split_data():
    test_data = pd.read_excel('magic04.xlsx', sheetname=0, skip_footer=16020)
    #code below prints correctly the data
    print test_data.iloc[:, 0:10] 

    #none of the code below work as expected 
    test1 = np.array(test_data.iloc[:, 0:10])
    test2 = test_data.as_matrix()
```

I'm really lost here. Any help would be very welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use `header=None` in `read_excel`. See the following:

```
df = pd.read_excel('stuff.xlsx')
>> df
    28.7967 16.0021 2.6449  0.3918  0.1982
0   31.6036 11.7235 2.5185  0.5303  0.3773
1   162.0520    136.0310    4.0612  0.0374  0.0187

>> df.ix[:, 1: 2]

0
1
```

Versus:

```
df = pd.read_excel('stuff.xlsx', header=None)
>> df

0   1   2   3   4
0   28.7967 16.0021 2.6449  0.3918  0.1982
1   31.6036 11.7235 2.5185  0.5303  0.3773
2   162.0520    136.0310    4.0612  0.0374  0.0187

>> df.ix[:, 1: 2]
    1   2
0   16.0021 2.6449
1   11.7235 2.5185
2   136.0310    4.0612
```

Comment: That worked!!! It worked with both ways: the attribute ".iloc[:, 0:X] " and the method "as_matrix()"! Really thanks!